# Symfony problems with .gitignore

Tags: php, git, symfony

I´m developing a web app with symfony3 and using GIT through GitKraken to a GitLab server.

I have this content in my .gitignore file:

```
# Cache, session files and logs (Symfony3)
/var/cache/*
/var/logs/*
/var/sessions/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!var/logs/.gitkeep
!var/sessions/.gitkeep
```

My problem is when I'm watching in GitKraken, I can see the unstaged files and it appears many files like:

```
    var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
    var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml
    var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerCompiler.log
    var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlGenerator.php
    var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php
    var/cache/dev/profiler/index.csv
    var/logs/dev.log
```

I want these files be ignored by git, as well as all temp files.

Thanks!

Comment: Make a fresh Symfony project and compare it's .gitignore file with yours.

Answer (score 0):

I use this `.gitignore`

```
!/var/cache
/var/cache/*
!/var/cache/.gitkeep
```

All files are ignored except `.gitkeep`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command git :

```
git rm --cached -r var
```

You can replace var with any folder you ignore.